# Android datarouter logcat error message

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

So I get my logcat spammed by this datarouter error. Anyone who can help me to fix this issue and tell me why it happens?

Oh I've tryed restarting phone and eclipse.

Edit: It seems to happen primarily on my Mac work computer.

Here is log of a complete spam it gives every 30 sec:

```
11-23 14:25:46.917: E/DataRouter(82): After the usb select 
11-23 14:25:46.917: E/DataRouter(82): Before checking the modem suspend state 
11-23 14:25:46.917: E/DataRouter(82): PDP is resumed now
11-23 14:25:46.917: E/DataRouter(82): After checking the modem suspend state 
11-23 14:25:46.917: E/DataRouter(82): Path set is DATA_PATH_CHAR_MODEM
11-23 14:25:46.917: E/DataRouter(82): Send [1] bytes to SMD. message:A
11-23 14:25:46.917: E/DataRouter(82): Sending data to SMD: Len = [1]
11-23 14:25:46.917: E/DataRouter(82):  buffer = [A]
11-23 14:25:46.917: E/DataRouter(82): Wrote 1 chars to EXTERNAL PORT fd=12 ch = 41
11-23 14:25:46.917: E/DataRouter(82): Before the usb select 
11-23 14:25:46.929: E/DataRouter(82): After the usb select 
11-23 14:25:46.929: E/DataRouter(82): Before checking the modem suspend state 
11-23 14:25:46.929: E/DataRouter(82): PDP is resumed now
11-23 14:25:46.929: E/DataRouter(82): After checking the modem suspend state 
11-23 14:25:46.929: E/DataRouter(82): Path set is DATA_PATH_CHAR_MODEM
11-23 14:25:46.929: E/DataRouter(82): Send [1] bytes to SMD. message:T
11-23 14:25:46.929: E/DataRouter(82): Sending data to SMD: Len = [1]
11-23 14:25:46.929: E/DataRouter(82):  buffer = [T]
11-23 14:25:46.929: E/DataRouter(82): Wrote 1 chars to EXTERNAL PORT fd=12 ch = 54
11-23 14:25:46.929: E/DataRouter(82): Before the usb select 
11-23 14:25:46.929: E/DataRouter(82): After the Modem Read select 
11-23 14:25:46.929: E/DataRouter(82): Read 1 chars from SMD Modem file fd = 12
11-23 14:25:46.929: E/DataRouter(82):  buf = A
11-23 14:25:46.929: E/DataRouter(82): Wrote 1 chars to USB PORT fd=29
11-23 14:25:46.929: E/DataRouter(82):  buf=A
11-23 14:25:46.929: E/DataRouter(82): Before the Modem Read select 
11-23 14:25:46.941: E/DataRouter(82): After the usb select 
11-23 14:25:46.941: E/DataRouter(82): Before checking the modem suspend state 
11-23 14:25:46.941: E/DataRouter(82): PDP is resumed now
11-23 14:25:46.941: E/DataRouter(82): After checking the modem suspend state 
11-23 14:25:46.941: E/DataRouter(82): Path set is DATA_PATH_CHAR_MODEM
11-23 14:25:46.941: E/DataRouter(82): Send [1] bytes to SMD. message:

11-23 14:25:46.941: E/DataRouter(82): Sending data to SMD: Len = [1]
11-23 14:25:46.941: E/DataRouter(82):  buffer = [
]
11-23 14:25:46.941: E/DataRouter(82): Wrote 1 chars to EXTERNAL PORT fd=12 ch = d
11-23 14:25:46.941: E/DataRouter(82): Before the usb select 
11-23 14:25:46.949: E/DataRouter(82): After the Modem Read select 
11-23 14:25:46.949: E/DataRouter(82): Read 8 chars from SMD Modem file fd = 12
11-23 14:25:46.949: E/DataRouter(82):  buf = T


11-23 14:25:46.949: E/DataRouter(82): OK

11-23 14:25:46.949: E/DataRouter(82): Wrote 8 chars to USB PORT fd=29
11-23 14:25:46.949: E/DataRouter(82):  buf=T


11-23 14:25:46.949: E/DataRouter(82): OK

11-23 14:25:46.949: E/DataRouter(82): Before the Modem Read select 
11-23 14:25:46.953: E/DataRouter(82): After the usb select 
11-23 14:25:46.953: E/DataRouter(82): Before checking the modem suspend state 
11-23 14:25:46.953: E/DataRouter(82): PDP is resumed now
11-23 14:25:46.953: E/DataRouter(82): After checking the modem suspend state 
11-23 14:25:46.953: E/DataRouter(82): Got command as string
11-23 14:25:46.953: E/DataRouter(82): last char is 13
11-23 14:25:46.953: E/DataRouter(82): last second char is 73
11-23 14:25:46.953: E/DataRouter(82): IsDeviceManagerCmd buffer in usb = AT+CGMI

11-23 14:25:46.953: E/DataRouter(82): Data Path Found is DATA_PATH_SMD 
11-23 14:25:46.953: E/DataRouter(82): Path set is DATA_PATH_SMD
11-23 14:25:46.953: E/DataRouter(82): Send [8] bytes to SMD. message:AT+CGMI

11-23 14:25:46.953: E/DataRouter(82): Sending data to SMD: Len = [8]
11-23 14:25:46.953: E/DataRouter(82):  buffer = [AT+CGMI
]
11-23 14:25:46.953: E/DataRouter(82): Wrote 8 chars to EXTERNAL PORT fd=12 ch = 41
11-23 14:25:46.953: E/DataRouter(82): Before the usb select 
11-23 14:25:46.957: E/DataRouter(82): After the Modem Read select 
11-23 14:25:46.957: E/DataRouter(82): Read 8 chars from SMD Modem file fd = 12
11-23 14:25:46.957: E/DataRouter(82):  buf = AT+CGMI

11-23 14:25:46.957: E/DataRouter(82): Wrote 8 chars to USB PORT fd=29
11-23 14:25:46.957: E/DataRouter(82):  buf=AT+CGMI

11-23 14:25:46.957: E/DataRouter(82): Before the Modem Read select 
11-23 14:25:46.960: E/DataRouter(82): After the Modem Read select 
11-23 14:25:46.960: E/DataRouter(82): Read 11 chars from SMD Modem file fd = 12
11-23 14:25:46.960: E/DataRouter(82):  buf = 

11-23 14:25:46.960: E/DataRouter(82): SAMSUNG

11-23 14:25:46.960: E/DataRouter(82): Wrote 11 chars to USB PORT fd=29
11-23 14:25:46.960: E/DataRouter(82):  buf=

11-23 14:25:46.960: E/DataRouter(82): SAMSUNG

11-23 14:25:46.960: E/DataRouter(82): Before the Modem Read select 
11-23 14:25:46.960: E/DataRouter(82): After the Modem Read select 
11-23 14:25:46.960: E/DataRouter(82): Read 6 chars from SMD Modem file fd = 12
11-23 14:25:46.960: E/DataRouter(82):  buf = 

11-23 14:25:46.960: E/DataRouter(82): OK

11-23 14:25:46.960: E/DataRouter(82): Wrote 6 chars to USB PORT fd=29
11-23 14:25:46.960: E/DataRouter(82):  buf=

11-23 14:25:46.960: E/DataRouter(82): OK

11-23 14:25:46.960: E/DataRouter(82): Before the Modem Read select 
11-23 14:25:46.964: E/DataRouter(82): After the usb select 
11-23 14:25:46.964: E/DataRouter(82): Before checking the modem suspend state 
11-23 14:25:46.964: E/DataRouter(82): PDP is resumed now
11-23 14:25:46.964: E/DataRouter(82): After checking the modem suspend state 
11-23 14:25:46.964: E/DataRouter(82): Got command as string
11-23 14:25:46.964: E/DataRouter(82): last char is 13
11-23 14:25:46.964: E/DataRouter(82): last second char is 77
11-23 14:25:46.964: E/DataRouter(82): IsDeviceManagerCmd buffer in usb = AT+CGMM

11-23 14:25:46.964: E/DataRouter(82): Data Path Found is DEVICE MANAGER 
11-23 14:25:46.964: E/DataRouter(82): Path set is DATA_PATH_DR_DEVICE_MANAGER
11-23 14:25:46.964: E/DataRouter(82): Message:AT+CGMM

11-23 14:25:46.964: E/DataRouter(82): processing AT command of length 8 
11-23 14:25:46.964: E/DataRouter(82): -------- buffer is =AT+CGMM

11-23 14:25:46.964: E/DataRouter(82): CGMM Request
11-23 14:25:46.964: E/DataRouter(82): [ro.product.model]: [GT-I9000]
11-23 14:25:46.964: E/DataRouter(82): write [16] bytes of data to USB fd[29]
11-23 14:25:46.964: E/DataRouter(82): write [6] bytes of data to USB fd[29]
11-23 14:25:46.964: E/DataRouter(82): Before the usb select
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a normal Error, in fact it is **not** an error at all. It is the (stupid?) way that the Android RIL (especially on Samsung devices) is presenting its debug logs. The "*DataRouter*" that you see, used to be classified as "Debug" and with the tag "AT" in older/other phones/modems. This is indeed very confusing to developers, unaware of these changes. Most likely because Samsung uses their own protocols to communicate with Baseband modem and not the standard AT set, which is interpreted somewhere along the way...

A good reference is the XDA thread:
"[How to talk to the Modem with AT commands](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1471241)"

Comment: It should be noted that _DataRouter_ messages come from the _drexe_ binary, while _AT_ messages come from the older _rild_ daemon, AFAIR.

Comment: Since I distro-upgraded my Linux development box I get a flood of exactly these messages from my Samsung phone. It wouldn't bother me that much but they overload the log message ring-buffer and I lose all the time the relevant messages. On top of that - and that's actually the worst problem: it screws up KDE. The GUI gets less and less responsive over time so I have to force a reboot at some point. It would be awesome if anybody could tell me a fix for that problem. How to mute DataRouter directly on the phone?

Answer (score 2):

You can use filters to ignore it. Use this regex (in eclipse):

```
tag:^((?!DataRouter).*)$
```

or this in command line:

```
adb logcat DataRouter:S
```

Comment: Thanks already using that :) but it doesn't answer the question as to what is the cause?