# E/DataRouter: Opening of the USB File failed fd is -1 & errno is 2

Tags: java, android, emulation

I have been search a lot,but didn't find any good solution,so here I am asking this question.
Whenever I run my android app on emulator I am getting this error :

> E/DataRouter: Opening of the USB File failed fd is -1 & errno is 2

What is the  real problem?

Thanks in advance.

P.S: this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242959/android-datarouter-logcat-error-message) didn't solve my problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android datarouter logcat error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242959/android-datarouter-logcat-error-message)

Comment: @niveshshastri I checked the answer but still confused and unable to understand the solution.can you explain it more?